# Resolving a running time of recursive relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion

My algorithm is given below i know that this algorithm has an exponential running time but i dont know how to show that mathematically. Does anyone have any idea on this?

if(n = 1 or n = 2) then return n

else
return 2 * RecursiveMNum(n - 1) * RecursiveMNum(n - 2)

Comment: no it's growing exponentially actually, try making a recursion tree and u will be able to see that.

Comment: @zerkms no as same state will be called more than once, ie if n=5 we will end up calling say f(2) more than once

Comment: Looks like the Ackermann function to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the complexity depends on the call `2 * RecursiveMNum(n - 1) * RecursiveMNum(n - 2)`, as the other will be computated on O(1).

So you can solve this using [Substitution](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec18.html).

> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) < 2T(n-1)

and now

> 2T(n-1)=2(2T(n-2))=2(2(2T(n-3)))=...=2^kT(n-k)=...=2^nT(0)=O(2^n)
>
> T(0) = Θ(1) (base case)

So you can say it has an `O(2^n)` complexity generally.

Comment: No problem! You can also see @sasha 's answer which is also correct and gives a closer bound for complexity, but is a bit more abstract to understand ( if you start studying algorithms complexity for first time ) !

Answer (score 0):

As you said for **n=1** one call to function is made to get the answer, same for **n=2**. The number of calls made for **n=3** is number of calls made for **n=1** plus number of calls made for **n=2**. Thus the sequence for number of calls  is **1,1,2,3 .....** . This indeed is the **Fibonacci** series. If you know the concept of golden numbers the ratio of two successive numbers in this series is about **1.6** ( [Golden Number](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/nature-golden-ratio-fibonacci.html) ) which is close to the golden number.
Now the successive ratio in an exponential series such as **a^n** is **a**. In our case we can say **a** is roughly about **1.6**. Thus indeed it has an exponential growth, ie. you can say it is **O(a^n)** where **a** is about **1.6**. You can also have a look at the closed form of nth fibonacci number here : [Nth Fibonacci](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) which justifies the argument as it has an exponential form.